How do I access a second drive that's on my Ubuntu desktop server with a Windows PC?
I recently started a project to make my old PC a home server that runs Ubuntu desktop. I can access the 300GB drive that the OS is on with other devices, but I can't access the 1TB drive. It's mounted and formatted. I just don't know how to access it on other devices that run Windows. I tried to map a network drive, but it didn't work on Windows although it seemed to work fine on Linux Mint when my dad tried it on his laptop. I tried to look for solutions, but I couldn't find any. I have no idea if I can use LVM for two drives that have different storage space sizes.

What is the format that the partition or drive is formatted to? It should be noted that Windows typically cannot access ext4 formatted filesystems. It's not impossible, but it would require installing third party software on the Windows computer to provide ext4 support and even then, it is rumored this may come with downsides like possible file corruption. If the drive is empty, then you could reformat it to a Windows supported format like ntfs or even better as like vfat or fat32 or whatever zip drives are typically formatted as.

Now, you refer to this as a server and you mention mapping a network drive. What type did you try to set up and what steps did you take? Apache and Samba should be compatible with windows — Apache through any web browser and Samba is supposed to be Windows compatible.

I use samba and my ext4 8tb extra drive has been made available to my normal /home/doug samba share via a link. I also had to allow samba to follow wide links in its configuration. Such a configuration might present a security issue for some users, but not in my use case.

im very new to this lol. The 300gb drive was formatted to ext4 and i had mapped it to a network drive on my windows pc and seems to work just fine with Samba. However my second drive is formatted on ntfs but i just dont know how to make a directory in it using ssh and samba so that i could map that drive into the network aswell
